# ShowLegend - length of legend items

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following example code and would like to make the lines in the legend longer - how can that be done?

Is there another possibility to plot such a legend when using `Show`?

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
SeedRandom[314];
data1 = RandomReal[10000, 100];
data2 = RandomReal[10000, 100];
plot1 = ListLogLogPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> {Red}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotRange -> Full];
plot2 = ListLogLogPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> {Green}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotRange -> Full];

ShowLegend[
 Show[plot1, plot2, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"data1,data2", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, 
    FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 800, 
  ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All, 
     50}}], {{{Graphics@{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {0.9, 0}}]}, 
    "data1"}, {Graphics@{Green, Line[{{0, 0}, {0.9, 0}}]}, "data2"}}, 
  LegendPosition -> {-0.7, -0.4}, LegendSize -> {0.2, 0.1}, 
  LegendShadow -> None, LegendTextSpace -> 10, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 10, 
    FontFamily -> "Calibri"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am confused though, you put the line lengths into the code by hand with this method.  If you change the two spots where you write `Line[{{0, 0}, {0.9, 0}}]` to `Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}}]` then the lines are longer.

Comment: somehow in my case it does not work (MMA 10.4.0 64bit, Win 10 Pro 64bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so the mantra around here is *"Don't use the PlotLegends package."*
Keep repeating that until you can resist the urge.

Here I'll just use `Inset` to place a `LineLegend` inside the frame, and I'll use the options for `LineLegend` to make the lines ridiculously long for example,

```
Show[plot1, 
 plot2,
  Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"data1,data2", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, 
       FontFamily -> "Calibri"},
  ImageSize -> 800, 
   ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All,  50}},
 Epilog -> Inset[
   LineLegend[{Red, Green}, {"data1", "data2"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed, LegendMarkerSize -> {100, 10}],
   Scaled[{.2, .2}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect ... thank you